# Error when trying to upload from php FORM into MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database, apache, phpmyadmin

i am working on web page and i need to connect my MySql dtatabse with php, i maneged to do that but i am stuck at uploading data from web page into database, i get error

> Notice: Undefined index: Naziv in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\HlodInfo\Skripte\upload.php on line 15
>
> Notice: Undefined index: Naslov in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\HlodInfo\Skripte\upload.php on line 16
>
> Notice: Undefined index: Vrsta_lesa in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\HlodInfo\Skripte\upload.php on line 17
>
> Notice: Undefined index: Kontakt in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\HlodInfo\Skripte\upload.php on line 18
>
> Notice: Undefined index: Ocena in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\HlodInfo\Skripte\upload.php on line 19

my code:
(admin.html)
FORM:

```
  <form action="Skripte/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       Naziv: <input type="text" name="Naziv">::
       Naslov <input type="text" name="Naslov">:: <br>
       Vrsta Lesa: <input type="text" name="Vrsta_lesa">::
       Kontakt <input type="text" name="Kontakt">::
       Ocena <input type="text" name="Ocena"> <br>

        <input type="submit" value="OK">
  </form>
```

PHP code (upload.php)

```
<?php



     $dbLink = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'hlodinfo');
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()) 
            die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());



        // Gather all required data
        $naziv = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_FILES['Naziv']['text']);
        $naslov = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_FILES['Naslov']['text']);
        $vrsta_lesa = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_FILES['Vrsta_lesa']['text']);
        $kontakt = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_FILES['Kontakt']['text']);
        $ocena = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_FILES['Ocena']['text']);


         // Create the SQL query
         $query = "INSERT INTO `odkupnik` ( `Naziv`, `Naslov`, `Vrsta_lesa`, `Kontakt`, `Ocena` )


                   VALUES ('{$naziv}', '{$naslov}', {$vrsta_lesa}, '{$kontakt}','{$ocena}')";


         $result = $dbLink->query($query);


         // Close the mysql connection
           $dbLink->close();


?>
```

I am still learing PHP and javascript and i am begginer. I apreciate your help and Thank you.

Comment: You are uploading a file using input text attribute. use the **file** attribute

Comment: Those are not _errors_ but _notices_.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

you are using `$_FILES` everywhere... it should be `$_POST`

```
        $naziv = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_POST['Naziv']);
        $naslov = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_POST['Naslov']);
        $vrsta_lesa = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_POST['Vrsta_lesa']);
        $kontakt = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_POST['Kontakt']);
        $ocena = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_POST['Ocena']);
```

put your `mysql insert code` in below given if condition

```
if(isset($_POST['Naziv']) && $_POST['Naziv']!='')
{
  //put your whole database code here...
}
```

Comment: OP is using enctype attribute in their form, so its clear that he wants to upload files.

Answer (score 0):

you have to do changes as below because your forms http method is POST

```
    // Gather all required data
    $naziv = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_POST['Naziv']);
    $naslov = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_POST['Naslov']);
    $vrsta_lesa = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_POST['Vrsta_lesa']);
    $kontakt = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_POST['Kontakt']);
    $ocena = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_POST['Ocena']);
```